# Tuleap Login Page Not Found

Tags: tuleap

I installed Tuleap on AWS EC2 RHEL 6.5 to evaluate the product.  The install went well except that when I try to login in that page cannot be found, it times out.  This is the URL that is attempting to find.

https://###########/account/login.php?return_to=/

I can navigate to other pages on the site without issue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
:D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP did not follow all the install instructions correctly. This error is unlikely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I had an ID10T moment but managed to fix my own problem simply by re-reading and properly following all install instructions.  In particular, I did not open up the ports recommended in those instructions.

Thanks
:D